# How to save and restore collapse state of devexpress xtragrid

Tags: save, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a question concerning the xtragrid from devexpress and google or
or devexpress pages did not help...

I have a xtragrid in my form. The form has different different views. Each view has some rows of data grouped by one or more columns of the data. I need a way to save the view (which rows are collapsed and which are not) PERSISTENT when loading another view and load it when I want to get that view again. It only works while the form has the specific handles of the rows...

So how can I save the state of the rows? The devexpress article "How to preserve the XtraGrid View state" did not... I can already save the grouping but not the "visual style" of the grid...

pls help

Comment: You can save a xtragrid view's layout to stream,registry or a XML file [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2370/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Save-and-Restore-Layout/Member-Table-Save-and-Restore-Layout). Does saving and restoring layout  work for you?

Comment: The view's layout will already be saved... BUT the state of collapsed and not collapsed rows will not be saved... I can save and restore the handles of these collapsed rows but don't they change when I get into another session?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [How to preserve the XtraGrid View state](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-preserve-the-xtragrid-view-state-e776) example(GitHub) which demonstrates how to preserve the XtraGrid's expansion, selection, focused row and its position related to the top, and restore this state later. You can use this example as a starting point and then add any required functionality.

Comment: I have read and moreover, **I have tried** the example I've mentioned above. This example clearly demonstrates the Grids' methods used in this situation and **It correctly works** within a single session. To persist the state between the sessions **you should manually add some code** to ensure state persistence. But this is a general programming question that is not related to GridView.